# PHP Get Input Value for File Name

Tags: php, post, input, filenames, export-to-excel

I have crud page which can export to excel when I click on a button.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="document.location.href='export/xls.php'" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
```

I want to export it with custom file name, so user can write the filename they want. In xls.php I'm using default file name

```
$filename = export;
$ext = "xlsx";
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$namafile.".".$ext."");
```

I want to replace $filename with user input. I try to use $_POST, but doesn't work.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="export/xls.php" method="post">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="filename" align="right" class="col-sm-3"><H4>File Name</H4></label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
         <input type="text" name="filename" class="form-control" id="filename">
      </div>
   </div>
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="document.location.href='export/xls.php'" data-dismiss="modal">
</form>
```

In xls.php

```
$filename = $_POST['filename'];
```

Is there any solution to get input value on xls.php?

Comment: either you submit your form to xls.php and get file name from $_POST variable or you can use JavaScript and send file name as GET parameter to your script.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually `POST`ing the form because of the `onClick` which changes your location before the form submits.

You need to do like:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="export/xls.php" method="post">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="filename" align="right" class="col-sm-3"><H4>File Name</H4></label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
         <input type="text" name="filename" class="form-control" id="filename">
      </div>
   </div>
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

Comment: Just added an explanatory note so the answer is more readable.

Comment: But if I don't add onclick(), they dont do anything, just dismiss modal. Should I add something on xls.php?

Comment: You can see my updated answer, you need to remove  data-dismiss="modal" from <input type="submit"> button, I guess its closing modal popup before submitting,

Comment: Still they don't do anything when I click it. Look like submit button doesn't run like onClick="document.location.href='export/xls.php'"